# Batch : Copy files changed on a specified date only

Tags: date, batch-file

Using batch script, I want to copy files to a folder using a specific date. I don't want to copy files after the specified date, I just want the files where modification date is exactly the specified date.

I used the XCOPY but the /D parameter copy files on AND after the specified date. 
Example :

```
XCOPY "D:\FOLDER" "V:\FOLDERBIS" /K /R /Y /I /D:05-25-2015 /E
```

This will copy files where modification date is greater or equal than may 25 2015, and I just want files where modification date is equal to this specific date.

Also, I can't use ROBOCOPY. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: can you use `WMIC` ?

Comment: Yes, I can but how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use `forfiles` (Win 7 or up) if you can't use `robocopy` (Win XP and up):

```
forfiles /D "2.06.2015" /c "cmd /c if @fdate EQU "02.06.2015" echo @file @fdate"
```

The reason for using this command is that it already parses the date.

Comment: My FORFILES uses MM/DD/YYYY format. Is FORFILES locale dependent?

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off

set "_date=20150525"
set "directory=D:\FOLDER"

for %%# in (%directory%) do (
    set "_path=%%~pn#"
    set "_drive=%%~d#"
)


set "_path=%_path:\=\\%\\"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('wmic datafile where "path='%_path%' and drive='%_drive%' " get LastModified^,Caption /Format:value') do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%A in ("%%#") do (
        if "%%A" equ "Caption" (
            set _fpath=%%B
        )

        if "%%A" equ "LastModified" (
            set _time=%%B
            if  !time:~0,8! equ %_date% (
                echo file !_fpath! has been created on !_time!
                rem :: remove echo if everything is ok
                echo copy "!_fpath!" "V:\FOLDERBIS"
            )
        )
    )

)
```

**EDIT**: file dates filtered with the wmic query

```
@echo off

set "_date=20150525"
set "directory=D:\FOLDER"


:: time zone is not used to deal better with - and + signs
for /f %%$ in ('wmic os get LastBootUpTime /format:value') do (
    for /f %%# in ("%%$") do set "%%#"
)
set offset=%LastBootUpTime:~21,4%

set "edate=%_date%235959.999999%offset%"
set "bdate=%_date%000000.000000%offset%"

for %%# in (%directory%) do (
    set "_path=%%~pn#"
    set "_drive=%%~d#"
)


set "_path=%_path:\=\\%\\"

for /f "skip=1 tokens=* delims=" %%# in (' wmic datafile where "path='%_path%' and drive='%_drive%'  and LastModified<='%edate%' and LastModified>='%bdate%'" get Caption /Format:table') do (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ("%%#") do (
        echo %%A
        copy "%%A" "V:\FOLDERBIS"
    )

)
```

Comment: You should use LastModified instead of CreationDate. Also, code is much simpler if you put the LastModified in the WHERE clause: `where "... and LastModified='20150525'"`

Comment: @dbenham my attempts to use ` LastModified='20150525'` or ` LastModified like '20150525%'` failed. It is datetime object and through the wmic looks like I can work only with strings.

Comment: @dbenham - looks like to create a datetime from string you need the whole thing - like this example date - `20150610150858.712825+180`

Comment: Oops, my mistake. You can specify a timestamp using `'YYYYMMDD'`, but that assumes midnight, and that is unlikely to match the file timestamp. All that is needed is a slight modification :-) `where "... and LastModified>='20150525' and LastModified<'20150526'"`

Comment: BTW - You are correct, if you want to specify both date and time, then you must use the entire 25 character timestamp string.